# Как организовать редьюсер Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

Есть стейт:

```js
const initialState = {
    tagsList: [],
    tagsGet: {},
    tagsUpdate: {},
    tagsCreate: {},
    tagsDelete: {},
}
```

Хочу чтобы tagsGet, tagsUpdate, tagsCreate, tagsDelete соответствовал свой редьюсер, но при этом чтобы эти редьюсеры изменяли tagsList. Можете подсказать как это сделать? Или если идея изначально плохая, то посоветовать как лучше организовать стейт и работу с ним.

Comment: Очень похоже что редюсеры что вы перечислили - это одна и таже сущность, какие-то tags. Так что можно все уместить в один редюсер, например tagsReducer.

Comment: @dresser да, вы правы, но со всеми -request -response -fail редьюсер получится кейсов на 15-20. Я начинающий, и я не знаю, нормальная ли это практика делать редьюсеры такого размера?

Comment: дело не в количестве кейсов, а в том что сущность tags распределена по разным местам - так не надо делать, а то что кейсов будет 15-20 - ничего страшного.

Comment: @dresser благодарю за ответ.